# Electrical conduit outside house

Tags: conduit

I have a hot tub going in on my patio in back of home.  Unfortunately my breaker panel is on opposite corner of home. It's a finished basement (walkout) so running cable inside to opposite end house seems to be a no go.  I'm trying to avoid digging a 100' trench.  Can I run conduit on outside of house just below the vinyl siding on concrete foundation?  It would be secured to house but only couple inches above ground level and inch below siding into concrete foundation.  Would want to make tight 90 at corner of house to, tricks there?  One last question, between disconnect panel and tub, can this 6' run just lay loose on top of patio in liquid tight flexible conduit?

Here are photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: outdoor conduits have to be underground

Comment: @Ruskes do you mean the part not attached to the house? The rest should be allowed.

Comment: @Ruskes I don't think that's true. As to the second question, that sounds like it would be a trip hazard.

Comment: So, if you're in the back yard facing the patio door, the conduit comes down the wall on the RIGHT side of the house from around the A/C, and the tub goes on the extension of the patio to the LEFT of the door?  You said you'll run the conduit along the foundation but how  will you get it past the patio door?  How about painting it yellow and running it at a level undeneath the bay window and directly underneath the deck?  Or making a few strategic holes in your basement walls, using very long drills and patching them up later?

Comment: Yes conduit start at service panel to right of a/c, down that whole right side of house and across entire rear wall pass patio door to tub on square part of patio.  I was thinking of running below patio door there is small area of few inches where the foundation exposed, basically running an inch off ground attached to house.  Running inside seems like a lot of trouble finished walls ceiling and long run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can attach conduit to the side of your foundation.

To make tight corners with conduit use a [LB Condulet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=LB%20condulet&t=vivaldi&iax=images&ia=images).

No you can't lay the raceway unsupported, and you can't use LFMC or LFNC where subject to physical damage, considering corrosive environment you pretty much need to use sch 80 PVC to the tub, then change to liquidtight inside the pool enclosure.  I don't think the NEC specifically addresses creating a tripping hazard, but you will certainly create a problem  with the building code.

Disconnect will need to be left or right of window, whatever it takes to be more than **5**' from inside edge of pool (**NEC 680.13**) with pool being at least 5' from porch light.  Looks like there is an existing receptacle to the left of door will satisfy the 6 to 20 ft. requirement.

Comment: If it's a trip hazard the disconnect is probably too far away.  The equipment is usually against a wall or fence and the disconnect on the wall or fence, with the LFMC/NC running along it.  You'd have to try very hard to trip over it.  I don't think I've ever seen a buried equipment whip.

Comment: Okay thanks for inputs. I added couple photos where hot tub would go and opposite corner of house where breaker panel is. Any thoughts on how others would get electric over there, where to mount disconnect that needs to be 6' min from tub. I could bite bullet and trench, but clay and rocks and sprinkler lines I have no idea where. So thinking just running conduit near ground attached to house all way around

Comment: If you put the tub close enough to the block wall that you cannot step between the tub and wall then you should be ok with anchors to slab. Not so clear about going below door.  I might think about going up to run underside of upper deck.

Comment: Under deck, under bay window, and along highest foundation line all seem to be in roughly a straight line.  Consider running a straight pipe at that level painted siding color.

Comment: I wouldn't use any kind of PVC along the edge of the patio, it's going to get banged a lot. And it's hard to see exactly but I think any conduit along the bottom of the door is going to trip people up when they are stepping up the step. So if you can get away with a half inch RMC, maybe buy a piece and lay it down under the door to see how well it fits.